# Passing a struct field as function parameter gives segmenttation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

new to C, I want to write a function taking 2 arguments, a file name and string. It should say if the string is in the file.

The function is as follows:
`

```
void find_string(char *filename, char *s)
{
    FILE *in = fopen(filename, "r");
    int i = 0;
    char line[100];
    while(fscanf(in, "%99[^\n]\n", line) == 1)
    {
         if (strstr(line, s))
               printf("Found occurrence of %s in file %s, line %s\n", s, filename, i);
         i++;
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

However, this does not seem to work if I apply it to my main function, which looks for files in a specified directory in Linux:

```
int main()
{
    char s[10];
    printf("Whatìs the string you want to find?\n");
    scanf("%10s", s);
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir("/var/log")) != NULL)
    {
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            char *dname;
            strcpy(dname, ent -> d_name);
            char *file_name = strcat("/var/log/", dname);
            find_string(file_name, s);
            printf("%s\n", strcat("/var/log/", dname));
       }
       closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

Someone tell me why the heck I'm getting a segmentation fault?

Comment: that strcat is illegal, use sprintf

Comment: The `strcpy()` into `dname` is also bogus, as `dname` is uninitialised.

Comment: Missing `if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR)`... Unless you want to try to search '.' and '..', too...

Answer (score 2):

`strcat` modifies its first argument, but you can't modify a string literal. You need to declare a buffer to hold the concatenated strings. You can use `sprintf()` to fill it in:

```
#define BASEDIR "/var/log/"

char file_name[sizeof BASEDIR + strlen(ent->d_name)];
sprintf(file_name, BASEDIR "%s", ent->d_name);
```